# My Static JS files Are Emitted when running npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, compiler-errors, npm-start

```
This is my React Javascript file
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="grid-container">
        <header className="row">
          <div>
            <a className="brand" href="/">
              My Web
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="/cart">Cart</a>
            <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
          </div>
        </header>
        <main>
          <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen}></Route>
          <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact></Route>
        </main>
        <footer className="row center">All right reserved</footer>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is the Error Im Getting while running (i used react-router-dom to build static pages) npm start

```
    assets by path static/js/*.js 1.56 MiB
      asset static/js/bundle.js 1.56 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
      asset static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.chunk.js 6.93 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
    asset index.html 1.8 KiB [emitted]
    asset asset-manifest.json 458 bytes [emitted]
    runtime modules 31.3 KiB 15 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.4 MiB 103 modules
    modules by path ./src/ 35.1 KiB
      modules by path ./src/*.js 9.44 KiB
        ./src/index.js 1.81 KiB [built] [code generated]
        + 3 modules
      modules by path ./src/*.css 9.22 KiB
        ./src/index.css 2.72 KiB [built] [code generated]
        ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css 6.49 KiB [built] [code generated]
      modules by path ./src/screens/*.js 9.9 KiB
        ./src/screens/HomeScreen.js 1.87 KiB [built] [code generated]
        ./src/screens/ProductScreen.js 8.03 KiB [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./src/components/*.js 6.56 KiB
        ./src/components/Product.js 2.92 KiB [built] [code generated]
        ./src/components/Rating.js 3.64 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.69.0 compiled successfully in 13380 ms
```

I tried build option but it didn't and my react app wont show anything in the browser worked I'm really stuck in this code really appreciate any help
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Check your React Router's version, it might be `v6`. If so, you should do like this,

```jsx
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="grid-container">
        <header className="row">
          <div>
            <a className="brand" href="/">
              My Web
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="/cart">Cart</a>
            <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
          </div>
        </header>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />}></Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} index></Route>
        </Routes>
        <footer className="row center">All right reserved</footer>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```